# Бот в телеграм несет чушь

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Смотрите, есть у меня бот, который работает по таблицам, но толи он с ума сошел, то ли я. В общем у меня есть проверка на наличие артикула товара в столбце А, но что, то компилятору мой говнокод не нравится, от слов к примерам
Функция где ошибка вылазит на 92 строчке, то есть на части (if message.text in listOfarticles:), ошибка - TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
def productAdd(message, index):
with open('UsersData/Users.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
with open(f'UsersData/{data["usernames"][index]}/config.json', 'r') as file:
    userdata = json.load(file)
listOfarticles = articles(userdata['excel_new_path'], 'A')
if message.text in listOfarticles:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уже добавили этот товар')
else:
    agent = get_agent()
    Reguest = request(message.text, agent)
    add_values_to_column(userdata['excel_new_path'], [message.text, Reguest["title"], Reguest["price"]], ['A', 'B', 'D'])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Товар({Reguest["title"]} - {Reguest["price"]} ₸) добавлен в писок')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы ввели не верное значение')
```

Также держите функцию articles

```
def articles(excel_path, sheetToAnalyze):
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_path)
sheet = workbook.active
column_data_a = sheet[sheetToAnalyze]
filled_cells = []
for cell_a in column_data_a:
    if cell_a.value is not None:
        filled_cells.append(str(cell_a.value))
if len(filled_cells) == 1:
    return 0
else:
    return (filled_cells)
```

Что не так, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `return 0` — что вы ожидали получить, запихивая число ноль в `if message.text in listOfarticles`?

Answer (score 2):

Я понял в чем была проблема, честно проблема максимально идиотская, аж стыдно стало. В общем, если присмотреться в коде есть 2 строчки, которые все ломали, а именно `if len(filled_cells) == 1: return 0`
что не так. Во первых, если в даблице нет данных(а у меня их не было), то выведется 0, что и выдавало ошибку, т.к. нельзя найти строчку в нуле`for cell_a in column_data_a:`, и решением проблемы будет 1. удалить просто эти 2 строчки. 2. заменить их на
`len(filled_cells) == 1: return []`

Comment: Молодец, что решил проблему самостоятельно, спасибо за уделённое время для написания ответа  :)

Answer (score -1):

```
def productAdd(message, index_list):
    import json
    from articles import articles
    from agent import get_agent
    from request import request
    from add_values_to_column import add_values_to_column
    
    with open('UsersData/Users.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    
    for index in index_list:
        with open(f'UsersData/{data["usernames"][index]}/config.json', 'r') as file:
            userdata = json.load(file)
        
        listOfarticles = articles(userdata['excel_new_path'], 'A')
        
        if message.text in listOfarticles:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уже добавили этот товар')
        else:
            agent = get_agent()
            Reguest = request(message.text, agent)
            add_values_to_column(userdata['excel_new_path'], [message.text, Reguest["title"], Reguest["price"]], ['A', 'B', 'D'])
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Товар({Reguest["title"]} - {Reguest["price"]} ₸) добавлен в список')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Каким образом этот код решает описанную в вопросе проблему? Для чего вы заменили `index` на `index_list`?